# How is this login table structure?

Tags: database-design

The structure is as follows:

For the main login
User:

```
user_id | email_id | username | password | is_active | is_banned | last_login
```

User_detail:

```
uname | fname | lname | phone_no
```

Should I move `is_active` and `is_banned` to `user_detail`, as it is checked just once?

Comment: What is the benefit of the second table? Why not just put it all in the User table as it is User information.

Comment: This is one to one relationship with same entity that can be merged into single user table.

Comment: You're missing the hash column.. Surely you're not storing the password in plain text.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow Asp.Net's Membership table structure. This has a one table for holding user input (username, real name, phone, email, etc), and one table for the back-end login system (password, is active, is banned, etc).

This way you have your tables divided out between functionality: One handles user account, other handles how/if they can log in.

However, it is perfectly reasonable to keep all User information in the Users table.

For more information, see [Database Normalization](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/283878).